QGIS - Upslope Area Function - Error
I am try to create map that shows the catchment of my reserach area. I already created the steams and related basins. Further, I would like to delete the basins that are not related with my catchment area with Upslope function.
However I have the following problem with the Uplslope area function. The system creates the catchment area that I select but the max. and min. values are changing between 100 and 100. In normal case it should be between 0 and 100. Therefore, when I crearted the vector file, it does not seperate the selected catchment area from the complete rest DEM file. I tried to change also the max. and min. values by setting up the min. as 0. However nothing is changing.
Do you have an opinion regarding the reason of the problem?

May you better explain the meaning of "the max. and min. values are changing between 100 and 100"?

Hello, thanks for your feedback. What I mean with legend is the symbology that we see under Layer properties. When a layer created with Upslope area function, the labels under symbology is 0 and 100. So I can be able to delete the area that is classified as 0 in order to visulise only my catchment area. But in my case the label value under symbology is classified automatically only with 100. Therefore I am not able to delete the area that stays out of my catchment.

So, the issue is in the symbology of the layer or in the data contained in the layer? If the formar, you can change the symbology as you want and you can set the "Accuracy" parameter (in the "Min/Max Value Settings" group) to the "Actual" value instead of "Estimate".

I tried to adjust the symbology but didnt help. The symbology is not the problem. Normally when I copy outlet point coordinates of my catchment area to the upslope area function, the system should clasify my catchment as 100 and the rest areas 0. So i can be able to delete are areas other than my catchment area when I create the vector layer. However the system somehow recognises only my catchment area and clasify it as 100, the rest areas doesnot recorded by the system which should be collected under 0 in the symbology. I dont really understand why the system doesnot finds the other areas.

It would be useful if you provided sample data and parameters in order to replicate the described behavior.

My complete sample document is 21 MB. Is there a possibility to share the documents via forum? I could not see any option other than adding comments? How can I share my sample data?

Just use a file sharing service and provide the URL needed to download the data.

The sample document is loaded to the link below. My problem is related with the Layer named 'Catchment'. It is shown as black and classified as 100. The other catchment areas on the map cannot be classified by the system. Therefore, I cannot remove the other catchments from my general map when I create vector layer.

https://we.tl/t-5xwCHvunLm

Please provide the exact QGIS version, SAGA-GIS version and SAGA-GIS plugin version used and exact steps you followed and parameter you used to generate the affected raster layer.
The "Catchment.sdat" raster layer is missing in the provided archive.

QGIS Version is the document named as ‘Sample_Document’ in the folder. But I uploaded again in the following link.
I did not really understand what you mean with SAGA-GIS version and SAGA-GIS plugin version.
The catchment area is saved to the folder below as well.
https://we.tl/t-fIZiZDEgPz

I included my steps and the file names that I saved after each steps below.
1- I included OSM Standard Map and adjusted my coordinates system. 2 -I downloaded the related DEM (n50_e009_1arc_v3). 3- I clipped my project area and reprojected the DEM according to my coordinate system (DEM_Clip_Rep) 4- I used SAGA (Fill sinks (wang&lui) function and created DEM_Fill file. 5- I used Strahler order function and created the streams (Strahler.sdat)

6- I defined a threshold value as 4 and redefined my streams. (Strahler4)  7- I used Channel network and drainage basin function and created my channels and basins (File name: Basin and Channels). 8- I used upslope area function to separate my catchment area from the other basin (File name: Catchment), I used DEM_Fill file.
